# How entropy is calculated when a non categorical feature is available when using Decision tree or random forest algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, random-forest, cart, entropy

How an entropy is calculated on non-categorical feature containing big amount of `unique` numbers?

Let me give you an example:

When we're having a categorical feature, we take the unique values, so if it contains 20 users with their respective countries, we would have only 5 unique countries:

[image]

These countries, then used to calculate the entropy related to the dependent feature.

However, when we have a non categorical data, how it would be calculated? Does the algorithm do the same and take the unique values and do its regular calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the feature is numeric, the best threshold value for splitting the classes is chosen. You even don’t need to have big number of unique values. For example, if the features are movie ratings, say $x$, between 1-10, the split will be like $x<\theta$. The best value of $\theta$ is chosen to maximize the information gain. Then you’ll calculate the entropies bases on data samples for $x<\theta$ and $x\geq \theta$ separately.

Comment: in your example, the best $\theta$ value is 5 so the calculations will be on $x<5$ and $x\geq 5$ right ???!!

Comment: Yes, one branch of the tree will represent samples satisfying $x\leq 5$, and the other will represent $x>5$. (You can place equality sign wherever you want.)

Comment: Is there any online tutorials for this specific case?

Comment: For entropy calculation on numeric fields.

Comment: And by the way, how the model knows that 5 is the best splitting value?

Comment: It searches fro all possible splits. This might be useful, although it's not entropy: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350-2006/lecture-10.pdf